# Web forms scaffolding option is not getting displayed in my VS2013 Update 3

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2013, scaffolding

Web form scaffolding option is not getting displayed in my VS2013 Update 3. I have tried installing the Web Forms Scaffolding from https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a6c3614f-83be-4749-afbc-8da394b6ea86/view/Reviews/0?showReviewForm=True but it says already installed for all templates.

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution :)

Need to install VS 2013 RC 5

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2013-update5-vs.aspx

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=46848